# My Ajax Call Is Not working when i type in textbox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHint(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>


<form>
    First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" />
</form>
<span id="txtHint"></span>
-------------------------------------


<?php

$a[]="Anna";
$a[]="Wenche";
$a[]="Vicky";

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
if (strlen($q) > 0)
  {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
    if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$a],0,strlen($q))))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint=$a[$i];
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint." , ".$a[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint == "")
  {
  $response="no suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: What is not working? When you look at Fiddler or Firebug do you see an Ajax call going to the server? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Is the error on the server or on the client? Have you tired calling the url that you are making the Ajax call in the browser directly? Does that work? You need to pin point where it is breaking.

Comment: check the call and response from Firebug, code is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$a],0,strlen($q))))
```

to

```
if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
```

Comment: Think we got a winner here! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (xmlhttp == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
Should BE
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

---------------------------

if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$a],0,strlen($q))))
Should BE
if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error will occur  on

```
strtolower(substr($a[$a],0,strlen($q))))
```

Here what is $a[$a] ..? Are like to executing for loop Then

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
     if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$a],0,strlen($q))))
```

please change like this

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
    {
     if (strtolower($q)==strtolower(substr($a[$i],0,strlen($q))))
```

$a replace with $i then only the $a[] is working

Answer (score -2):

```
<form>
    FirstN<input type="text" onkeyup="return showHint(this.value);" size="20" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you have to do that? A good programmer would add it unobtrusively and there is no need for a return statement unless you need to cancel the event which you can do through the event object itself.

Comment: Willing to bet that this answer did not magically make the poster's code work.

Comment: @Karthikeyan's `What am I?` A person that knows your answer is not correct?
@user741429 Please answer my comment under your question. Thank You!

Comment: sorry epascarello im sorry budddy